# httpResponse though JSONParser is not exceturing my url. it seems that it doesnt add the params

Tags: android, json, url, parameters

in doing a login page and i pass some parameters to the JSONParser but it seems to not add the params why?

here is the code:
this method set the parameters

```
public JSONObject loginUser(String login, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secret", "7658474y33"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", login));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ping", "1"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("retina", "1"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_token", ""));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_name", ""));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_model", ""));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_sys", ""));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
```

and this is the JSONParser class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            Log.i("JSONParser", httpPost.getURI().toString());
            Log.i("param.size", Integer.toString(params.size()));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            Log.i("JSONParser", "is ok");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("JSONParserException", "1");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("JSONParserException", "2");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("JSONParserException", "3");
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

and i get this error

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Comment: There are more than 1000 results for the same in SO. Please spend some time in searching also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException** error

that mean you are execute your  function in your Main UI thread.  But you but cant work with network in UI` thread...

For that you have to use **AsyncTask** or use **Thread with Handler** or **runOnUiThread()** for update your UI...

for more info you should go with [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Comment: can update  `UI` in main thread but can't work with network in `UI` thread

Comment: yes i know this but the real problem is that ist not ddoing the post request!

Answer (score 1):

Use `AsyncTask` for same. Try this:

```
class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, RSSFeed> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected RSSFeed doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url= new URL(urls[0]);
            SAXParserFactory factory =SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser=factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xmlreader=parser.getXMLReader();
            RssHandler theRSSHandler=new RssHandler();
            xmlreader.setContentHandler(theRSSHandler);
            InputSource is=new InputSource(url.openStream());
            xmlreader.parse(is);
            return theRSSHandler.getFeed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed feed) {
        // TODO: check this.exception 
        // TODO: do something with the feed
    }
}
```

How to use ...

```
new YourAsyncTask().execute(urlToRssFeed);
```